# PHPStorm switch statement 'break' indenting

Tags: coding-style, phpstorm, indentation

PHPStorm is a very nice IDE, but it does one thing that annoys me.

I (and my team) write our switch statements like so:

```
switch ($foo) {
    case 'a' :
        // some code
    break;
}
```

PHPStorm auto-corrects this to be

```
switch ($foo) {
    case 'a' :
        // some code
        break;
}
```

Note that the `break` is indented along with the code. I don't want this to happen.

I've looked in the code style section, but the only option for switches is to indent the case branches.

Does anyone know how stop PHPStorm from doing this?

Comment: Still no solution? I'm looking for this too.

Comment: @MaugLee - It took a couple of years, but the solution is finally here =]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change this default behavior in

```
settings | Editor | Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces
```

uncheck **indent 'break' from 'case'** option

Comment: That's the one! They finally added it as an option in V9. Like I said before, I'm actually used to it being indented now, but hopefully this question will help other people.

Comment: Option not available for JavaScript :( - PhpStorm 9.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Based on the recommendations in [PSR-2 on code style](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#user-content-52-switch-case), PHPStorm displays it the recommended way.

If you really want to change it, you can do it in `Editor > Code style > PHP > Wrapping and Braces` under the `'switch' statement` and uncheck the `Indent 'break' from 'case`.

*Disclaimer, the screenshot is from IntelliJ, but you should be able to find the same setting in the same location*
[image: Related screenshot]

Comment: Strange - it's not there in the latest version of PHPStorm: https://www.dropbox.com/s/miblix2003meha9/Screenshot%202015-04-08%2016.59.00.png?dl=0

Comment: You will have to wait for PHPStorm to be updated to match current version of IntelliJ then I guess. Sorry for the false hope

Comment: No worries - if I'm honest I've gotten used to having it indented now - but it's still worth keeping this question up to date in case someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open the **Settings** .
Choose Code Style -> PHP as below

Change the `Continuation Indent` value to 0 as shown. **Done**.

[image]

Comment: @Grim... Can you describe `that didn't work` ? May i know your version. This is on 5.0.3.

Comment: I'm on 6.0.3, and changing the continuation indent made no difference, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you also have to go by the logic that the application is pointing out, a break is not necessarily the end of a case statement. You could have comments after the break statement, both logically and visually. The break is a child of that particular case statement.